# Ultra low noise power supply for pre-amp

Tags: power-supply, transistors, amplifier, ripple, preamp

I have designed the following power supply smoothing circuit for my turn table preamp. This will be powered by a 24V 'wall-wart' type adapter.

I tried to combine a transistor/zenner diode voltage regulator with a capacitance multiplier, the 0.1uf caps are for RF suppression.

[image: my pwr filter]

As far as I can tell this works really well, but I'm not quite sure how well it will work in real life.
My question is will this work well for ripple/noise rejection? 
What improvements can I make here?
'pwr_out' directly powers the collector resistors of the amplifying transistors at only about 2mA total draw (per channel) as its only driveing an amplifier with a 47k input impedance.

My full circuit:
[image: full]

Thankyou.

Comment: Why don't you add a series base resistor, leaving C5 on the base? As you have it the capacitance multiplier effect is compromised by the low dynamic resistance of the zeners. Of course there will be a degraded load regulation.

Comment: *My question is will this work well for ripple/noise rejection?* How "well working" does it need to be? Will it remove **all** noise and ripple? Nope but no regulator can do that. Why not simply use a regulator IC (like an LM78L15 with a 3 V zener diode or an LM317?).

Comment: This is cheaper, I learn more and if the simulation is accurate this will happily do the job.

Comment: Have you had hum issues in the past?

Comment: What hum rejection are you measuring?

Comment: A moving coil cartridge can be 0.5mV signal and 80 db hum reduction requires 50nV hum.. You may get 100x more on your cable unless balanced and shielded. So what have you learned? Not much without specs.

Comment: I will edit this post to include my full circuit..

Comment: Try to include all sources of noise. if measured.

Comment: This is all just simulated before I build it. just don't want to waste my time if its super nosey. I have simulated sine waves at different frequency's from supply voltage in ltspice. from a 2V ripple @ 60hz (not expecting anything that bad), the output shows only about 2mV ripple. I don't yet know how to measure in db in the software.

Comment: I would like to test this on a breadboard before I start to design a PCB, but I think it will just pick up lots of interference on a breadboard due to long the tracks inside the breadboard?